# Hadoop 2.5.2 on Mesos 0.21.0 - Failed to fetch URIs for container

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, mesos

I'm trying to run a simple `WordCount` example on Mesos with Hadoop 2.5.2. I've successfully set up HDFS (actually got a YARN set up behind this and it is working fine). Mesos master is running and got 4 slaves connected to it. The Hadoop library for Mesos is 0.0.8.

The configuration for Hadoop 2.5.2 is (`mapred-site.xml`):

```
<configuration>
        <property>
                <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
                <value>*.*.*.*:9001</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>mapred.job.tracker.http.address</name>
                <value>*.*.*.*:50030</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>mapred.jobtracker.taskScheduler</name>
                <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MesosScheduler</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>mapred.mesos.taskScheduler</name>
                <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobQueueTaskScheduler</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>mapred.mesos.master</name>
                <value>*.*.*.*:5050</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>mapred.mesos.executor.uri</name>
                <value>hdfs://*.*.*.*:9000/hadoop-2.5.0-cdh5.2.0.tgz</value>
        </property>
</configuration>
```

I've got the following logs from all my slaves (example):

> dbpc42: I1202 00:03:12.066195 11232 launcher.cpp:137] Forked child
>   with pid '18714' for container 'c10c2d2b-bf4b-469b-97a2-60c9720773b4'
>
> dbpc42: I1202 00:03:12.068272 11232 containerizer.cpp:571] Fetching
>   URIs for container 'c10c2d2b-bf4b-469b-97a2-60c9720773b4' using
>   command '/opt/mesos-0.21.0/build/src/mesos-fetcher'
>
> dbpc42: I1202
>   00:03:12.140894 11226 containerizer.cpp:946] Destroying container
>   'c10c2d2b-bf4b-469b-97a2-60c9720773b4'
>
> dbpc42: E1202 00:03:12.141315
>   11229 slave.cpp:2787] Container 'c10c2d2b-bf4b-469b-97a2-60c9720773b4'
>   for executor 'executor_Task_Tracker_93' of framework
>   '20141201-225046-698725789-5050-19765-0003' failed to start: Failed to
>   fetch URIs for container 'c10c2d2b-bf4b-469b-97a2-60c9720773b4': exit
>   status 256
>
> dbpc42: I1202 00:03:12.242033 11231 containerizer.cpp:1117]
>   Executor for container 'c10c2d2b-bf4b-469b-97a2-60c9720773b4' has
>   exited dbpc42: I1202 00:03:12.243896 11225 slave.cpp:2898] Executor
>   'executor_Task_Tracker_93' of framework
>   20141201-225046-698725789-5050-19765-0003 exited with status 1

Job tracker running fine, with the `hadoop jar` command the job stucks at *map 0% reduce 0%*. In mesos cluster information the `TASKS_LOST` counter goes all the way up until I kill the job. Mesos and the JobTracker runs as root, the job runs as user `hdfs`.

What is this URI problem all about?

Thank you for your kind help or hint!

(I'll provide more information if needed.)

**UPDATE**

Starting a slave on the same PC where the master runs will get tasks to the staging status. 5, each time.

The `mapred-mesos.executor.uri` has been changed from the IP to `dbpc41` (master PC).

```
<property>
     <name>mapred.mesos.executor.uri</name>
     <value>hdfs://dbpc41:9000/hadoop-2.5.0-cdh5.2.0.tgz</value>
</property
```

The other 4 slaves are still losing tasks due to (probably) unable to fetch the executor URI.

These are the logs from the 5th slave running on the same PC where the master do:

> I1202 16:17:57.434345  1405 containerizer.cpp:571] Fetching URIs for
>   container '5f33123b-00eb-4e05-9dcc-30f16f5eee44' using command
>   '/opt/mesos-0.21.0/build/src/mesos-fetcher' I1202 16:18:08.620708 
>   1412 slave.cpp:2840] Monitoring executor 'executor_Task_Tracker_445'
>   of framework '20141201-225046-698725789-5050-19765-0012' in container
>   '5f33123b-00eb-4e05-9dcc-30f16f5eee44' I1202 16:18:09.022902  1407
>   containerizer.cpp:1117] Executor for container
>   '5f33123b-00eb-4e05-9dcc-30f16f5eee44' has exited I1202
>   16:18:09.022964  1407 containerizer.cpp:946] Destroying container
>   '5f33123b-00eb-4e05-9dcc-30f16f5eee44' W1202 16:18:11.369912  1407
>   containerizer.cpp:888] Skipping resource statistic for container
>   5f33123b-00eb-4e05-9dcc-30f16f5eee44 because: Failed to get usage: No
>   process found at 11093 W1202 16:18:11.369971  1407
>   containerizer.cpp:888] Skipping resource statistic for container
>   5f33123b-00eb-4e05-9dcc-30f16f5eee44 because: Failed to get usage: No
>   process found at 11093 I1202 16:18:11.399648  1412 slave.cpp:2898]
>   Executor 'executor_Task_Tracker_445' of framework
>   20141201-225046-698725789-5050-19765-0012 exited with status 1 I1202
>   16:18:11.401949  1412 slave.cpp:2215] Handling status update TASK_LOST
>   (UUID: 959709c2-5546-41fd-9af3-09f024bb6354) for task Task_Tracker_445
>   of framework 20141201-225046-698725789-5050-19765-0012 from @0.0.0.0:0
>   W1202 16:18:11.402245  1409 containerizer.cpp:852] Ignoring update for
>   unknown container: 5f33123b-00eb-4e05-9dcc-30f16f5eee44 I1202
>   16:18:11.403017  1410 status_update_manager.cpp:317] Received status
>   update TASK_LOST (UUID: 959709c2-5546-41fd-9af3-09f024bb6354) for task
>   Task_Tracker_445 of framework
>   20141201-225046-698725789-5050-19765-0012 I1202 16:18:11.403437  1406
>   slave.cpp:2458] Forwarding the update TASK_LOST (UUID:
>   959709c2-5546-41fd-9af3-09f024bb6354) for task Task_Tracker_445 of
>   framework 20141201-225046-698725789-5050-19765-0012 to
>   master@157.181.165.41:5050 I1202 16:18:11.448752  1409
>   status_update_manager.cpp:389] Received status update acknowledgement
>   (UUID: 959709c2-5546-41fd-9af3-09f024bb6354) for task Task_Tracker_445
>   of framework 20141201-225046-698725789-5050-19765-0012 I1202
>   16:18:11.449354  1408 slave.cpp:3007] Cleaning up executor
>   'executor_Task_Tracker_445' of framework
>   20141201-225046-698725789-5050-19765-0012 I1202 16:18:11.449707  1405
>   gc.cpp:56] Scheduling
>   '/tmp/mesos/slaves/20141201-225046-698725789-5050-19765-S4/frameworks/20141201-225046-698725789-5050-19765-0012/executors/executor_Task_Tracker_445/runs/5f33123b-00eb-4e05-9dcc-30f16f5eee44'
>   for gc 6.99999479755852days in the future I1202 16:18:11.450034  1409
>   gc.cpp:56] Scheduling
>   '/tmp/mesos/slaves/20141201-225046-698725789-5050-19765-S4/frameworks/20141201-225046-698725789-5050-19765-0012/executors/executor_Task_Tracker_445' for gc 6.9999947929037days in the future I1202 16:18:11.450147  1408
>   slave.cpp:3084] Cleaning up framework
>   20141201-225046-698725789-5050-19765-0012 I1202 16:18:11.450213  1406
>   status_update_manager.cpp:279] Closing status update streams for
>   framework 20141201-225046-698725789-5050-19765-0012 I1202
>   16:18:11.450381  1412 gc.cpp:56] Scheduling
>   '/tmp/mesos/slaves/20141201-225046-698725789-5050-19765-S4/frameworks/20141201-225046-698725789-5050-19765-0012'
>   for gc 6.99999478812444days in the future I1202 16:18:12.441505  1405
>   slave.cpp:1083] Got assigned task Task_Tracker_472 for framework
>   20141201-225046-698725789-5050-19765-0012 I1202 16:18:12.442337  1405
>   gc.cpp:84] Unscheduling
>   '/tmp/mesos/slaves/20141201-225046-698725789-5050-19765-S4/frameworks/20141201-225046-698725789-5050-19765-0012'
>   from gc I1202 16:18:12.442617  1405 slave.cpp:1193] Launching task
>   Task_Tracker_472 for framework
>   20141201-225046-698725789-5050-19765-0012 I1202 16:18:12.444263  1405
>   slave.cpp:3997] Launching executor executor_Task_Tracker_472 of
>   framework 20141201-225046-698725789-5050-19765-0012 in work directory
>   '/tmp/mesos/slaves/20141201-225046-698725789-5050-19765-S4/frameworks/20141201-225046-698725789-5050-19765-0012/executors/executor_Task_Tracker_472/runs/2310c642-02bf-401b-954c-876c88675c31'
>   I1202 16:18:12.444756  1405 slave.cpp:1316] Queuing task
>   'Task_Tracker_472' for executor executor_Task_Tracker_472 of framework
>   '20141201-225046-698725789-5050-19765-0012 I1202 16:18:12.444793  1406
>   containerizer.cpp:424] Starting container
>   '2310c642-02bf-401b-954c-876c88675c31' for executor
>   'executor_Task_Tracker_472' of framework
>   '20141201-225046-698725789-5050-19765-0012' I1202 16:18:12.447434 
>   1406 launcher.cpp:137] Forked child with pid '11549' for container
>   '2310c642-02bf-401b-954c-876c88675c31' I1202 16:18:12.448652  1406
>   containerizer.cpp:571] Fetching URIs for container
>   '2310c642-02bf-401b-954c-876c88675c31' using command
>   '/opt/mesos-0.21.0/build/src/mesos-fetcher'

Comment: What version of Mesos are you using?
What version of hadoop-mesos are you using?
Are you following a particular tutorial, or just using the README from https://github.com/mesos/hadoop ?

Comment: @Adam I'm using Mesos 0.21.0 and the library for Hadoop 0.0.8. Yes,  I was following that README from GitHub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checked executor logs (`stderr` in `/tmp/mesos/slaves/...`) and found out that `JAVA_HOME` was not set, so the `hadoop dfs` command was not able to run to fetch the executor. The URI was perfect, the `JAVA_HOME` was not set. Additionally I had to set `HADOOP_HOME` when starting the slaves.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the Mesos slave cannot fetch one of the URIs, likely the executor itself.

Did you upload your modified Hadoop on Mesos distribution (including the hadoop-mesos-0.0.8.jar) to `hdfs://*.*.*.*:9000/hadoop-2.5.0-cdh5.2.0.tgz` as specified by mapred.mesos.executor.uri? Is it accessible from the slave?

Comment: Yes, I did upload it. How can I check the accessibility from a slave correctly?

Comment: I've also tried to specify the `mapred.mesos.executor.uri` as IP address and FQDN. The file itself is in the possession of user `hdfs`, that is running the JobTracker. Also tried to run JobTracker with root. The file got 777 permissions.

Comment: I'm running a HDFS from Hadoop version 2.5.2. Could be there any HDFS incompatibility to Mesos 0.21.0?